# Looking for this short-story about a lone man's space travel, although details are a bit vague

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

As I remember it, this short-story was about a man travelling alone through space (our galaxy at least to start).

He had his favorite music and books (etc) with him and, I believe, his cat.

It was very cerebral and all about ruminating on the reality of travelling through the vast distances of nothingness of space (e.g. years between planets, etc).

I don't think he dies in the end, but, again, not 100% sure...

I also believe it was pre-1990's and perhaps from one of the classic/giant Sci-fi writers, but I'm not 100% sure of this.

Some others' suggestions that weren't it:

- Philip K. Dick - "I Hope I Shall Arrive Soon"
- Ray Bradbury - "Icarus Montgolfier Wright"
- Robert Heinlein - "Ordeal in Space"
- Alfred Bester - "The Stars My Destination"
- Ray Bradbury - "Kaleidoscope"
- Martin Caiden - "Marooned"
- Stephen King - "The Jaunt"
- Arthur C Clarke "The Star"
- John Varley - "The Pusher"

Comment: Do you happen to recall *why* he was travelling through space? Did he spend all his time in space, or did he land on planets from time to time? Did he meet any space aliens?

Comment: RE: Why -- Other than exploration/knowledge: no

He never left the ship, did not encounter aliens, and spent his time only in the ship (awake, no hypersleep that I remember).

Comment: I've read over half of your rejected suggestions, and I'm wondering why they were suggested in the first place, as the ones I've read bear no resemblance at all to your description.

Comment: Is it likely to have been in a magazine such as Analog, Asimov's, Fantasy & Science Fiction, or Omni (and which zines were you reading regularly at the time), or would it have been in a paperback or hardcover anthology or collection? (It doesn't *sound* like an Analog story from your description.)

Comment: The suggestions were from others. I just put them up to avoid getting them again.

I don't think it was Analog (etc). It is more likely to have been an anthology/collection or a story in a magazine, but I don't think it was specifically a SciFi-type mag.

Not much help, I know...

Comment: If it's about a group of people who were given mathematical puzzle books to help pass the time (only to learn that their journey was pointless, and math was the actual purpose), I might have a clue.

Comment: Nope, it was only one person...But, that does sound interesting, so can you tell me anyway :-)

Comment: For some reason your description makes me think Larry Niven but I'm not sure why.  Barrycarter23 makes me think of Pohl or Preuss.

Comment: @EmsleyWyatt Niven's stories "The Ethics of Madness" and "Rammer" both involve single-crewed ramscoop vessels on long journeys but neither matches the OPs description at all well.

Answer (score 6):

"Med Ship", a collection of four stories by Murray Leinster [currently published by Baen Books](http://www.baen.com/med-ship.html), may be what you're describing.

Calhoun, the main character, flies from planet to planet providing medical services.  His companion Murgatroyd is a small animal which I always thought was somewhat cat-like.  Calhoun spends a lot of his in-transit time in "deep thought", and he does have books and music.

A paragraph from the link above:

> Calhoun is the best the Med Service has, and hard experience has
>   taught him that often the major obstacle to curing the sick is ... the
>   sick. And removing that kind of obstacle may take very strong
>   medicine. To find a cure for a disease, Calhoun has the help of his
>   small animal companion Murgatroyd, a formal—a species with the most
>   powerful immune system in the galaxy. But to find a cure for hysteria,
>   prejudice, crime, and even war is much more complicated, requiring
>   considerable ingenuity. Fortunately, ingenuity is something that
>   Calhoun has in good supply...

Comment: I don't remember there being a goal (saving lives, etc.) or anything this elaborate. The story I remember was only about the person setting off into space in this way (alone, with books and music, etc.). It described more the loneliness and emptiness of space that lay in front of him, but it basically stopped there.

That being said, this series sounds quite interesting! I ordered a copy of the book. So, even if it isn't what I was thinking of, you gave me something new and interesting to read either way!! 

Thanks :-)

Comment: Read Med Ship on your recommendation. Enjoyed it (thanks!), but it's not what I was lokking for. I'm pretty sure the story I'm referring to was either a novella or, more likely, a short-story

Answer (score -1):

Try James Tiptree Jr's "The man who walked home"

Comment: You could improve this answer by explaining how this story matches the one described in the question. Take a look at [this post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9444/how-to-write-a-good-story-id-answer) for tips on how to writer a good story ID answer.

Comment: Isn't a story of reverse time travel which begins in catastrophe?

Comment: There are no spaceships in that story.